# VLD3.8 in NEON ASM doesn't work like the vld3q_u8 documentation says it should?

Tags: assembly, optimization, arm, neon

According to the ARM reference we have 2 functions to load 8 and 16 uint8_t instances respectively:

```
 uint8x16x3_t  vld3q_u8(__transfersize(48) uint8_t const * ptr);  
                                             // VLD3.8 {d0, d2, d4}, [r0]

 uint8x8x3_t vld3_u8(__transfersize(24) uint8_t const * ptr);  
                                             // VLD3.8 {d0, d1, d2}, [r0]
```

In NEON intrinsics I tried vld3q_u8 and everything worked successfully that 16 * 3 of uint8 elements was loaded; however, when I used VLD3.8 {d0, d2, d4} in NEON assembly only 8 * 3 of uint8 elements was loaded.

It seems to me that d1, d3 and d5 registers weren't used.

I would like to use q0(d0, d1), q1(d2, d3), and q3(d4, d5) registers fully to load 16 * 3 of uint8 elements.

Could anyone help ?

```
//sample code:
vld3.8 {d0, d2, d4}, [%[A]]!
vst.3.8 {d0, d2, d4}, [%[C]]!
```

I am building this for a 32bit ARM architecture.

Comment: reference: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0472j/DUI0472J_armcc_user_guide.pdf

Comment: Please include your exact code so this is a [mcve].  Also, are you building for AArch64, or for 32-bit ARM?  (In AArch64, d1 isn't the high half of q0; there are 32 separate q registers.)

Answer (score 3):

> It seems to me that d1, d3 and d5 registers weren't used

Indeed they're not, unless you load them. What the intrinsics reference isn't very clear about is that the Q-form load/store intrinsics expand to *two* instructions each - the underlying `vldn`/`vstn` instructions only target D registers, but can do so either consecutively, or with a stride of 2, such that a pair of instructions can load pairs of registers in the appropriate order.

Here's a disassembled example of what a `vld3q_u8` intrinsic actually looks like in-situ:

```
0:   f460650f        vld3.8  {d22,d24,d26}, [r0]
4:   e2802018        add     r2, r0, #24
...
c:   f462750f        vld3.8  {d23,d25,d27}, [r2]
...
```

That's targeting a `uint8x16x3_t` variable for which the compiler has apparently allocated Q11-13.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. That makes sense, so that means even if I use vld3q_u8 or (vld3_u8 + loop) in intrinsics it takes about the same amount of time ? (the speed depends on the number of vld3.8 calls in assembly). Am I correct ?

Comment: On most DSP algorithms the speed of VLD will be dominated by how well you manage to keep data hot in L1 or L2 cache (or how well you preload), not the one or two cycle differences in instruction issue cycles.